# Force assigntion of a new property to aiogram's message.from_user (aiogram 3)

Tags: python, pydantic, aiogram

I'm migrating to aiogram 3.0. While rewriting code of my bot's middleware, I had a problem: the bot uses ORM to store user's data, so in order to easily access ORM model in handler I used to assign it as a property via middleware like this:

```
model = db.get_user(message.from_user.id)
message.from_user.model = model
```

In older aiogram it worked fine but now it throws error:

```
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for User
model
  Instance is frozen [type=frozen_instance, input_value=<database.models.User obj...t at 0x000001CFE141BC10>, input_type=User]
```

I guess that's because `Message` is now immutable object and 100% solution is to use `db.get_user(message.from_user.id)` instead. But I already have a lot of handlers where it is used, so rewriting all of them would take a lot of time

I would like to know if there is a way to force this property assignation